# cv::Mat header information changes when using a reference

Tags: opencv

I'm declaring a

```
cv::Mat imageMatrix(bitmapEntry->GetHeight(), bitmapEntry->GetWidth(), ConvertToCVType(bitmapEntry), imageBytes);
cv::Mat rightImageMat;
cv::Mat leftImageMat;
SplitCVMatrix(imageMatrix, leftImageMat, rightImageMat);
```

I get 2160 rows and 7680 cols which is expected.

When I pass this matrix to a function by reference the matrix's structure is different:

```
OVOpenCVFilter::SplitCVMatrix(cv::Mat &matrix, cv::Mat &leftSplitMatrix, cv::Mat &rightSplitMatrix)
```

The rows are equal to 2 the step to 7680 and the cols to 2160.

I'm not receiving the same structure that I passed. Seems like I'm getting what at's the address, what should I deal to pass my matrix correctly?

Comment: Please post the ENTIRE relevant code sections, and also post the relevant `Mat` field values (rows, cols, step, etc...). We can't help as well without that information.

Comment: I've added some details. That's all there is to it. The bitmapEntry is fine and all the getters too, the convert is also working fine. So the original imageMatrix is constructed correctly. And when I'm talking about the rows etc, I'm just running this in debugging mode and looking up the values.

Comment: What do ConvertToCVType, and SplitCVMatrix look like? What is the length of imageBytes?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this code:

```
void SplitCVMatrix(cv::Mat &matrix, cv::Mat &leftSplitMatrix, cv::Mat &rightSplitMatrix) {
    printf("rows: %d, columns: %d, step: %ld", matrix.rows, matrix.cols, matrix.step[0]);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    cv::Mat imageMatrix(2160, 7680, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(128, 128, 128));
    cv::Mat rightImageMat;
    cv::Mat leftImageMat;
    SplitCVMatrix(imageMatrix, leftImageMat, rightImageMat);

    return 0;
}
```

and got this output:

`rows: 2160, columns: 7680, step: 23040`

So I don't agree with your assertion that the original imageMatrix is constructed correctly (or else there is something happening in `SplitCVMatrix` that you aren't showing us). You need to look more closely at the values being passed to the imageMatrix constructor.

Comment: I will look into it tomorrow when I get access to my office.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void printFromReference(Mat& src)
{
    cout << "Rows: " << src.rows << endl;
    cout << "Cols: " << src.cols << endl;
    cout << "Step: " << src.step << endl;
    cout << "Size: " << src.rows*src.cols*src.elemSize1() << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Mat bigImage(2160, 7680, CV_8UC1);

    cout << "Before: " << endl;
    cout << "Rows: " << bigImage.rows << endl;
    cout << "Cols: " << bigImage.cols << endl;
    cout << "Step: " << bigImage.step << endl;
    cout << "Size: " << bigImage.rows*bigImage.cols*bigImage.elemSize1() << endl;

    cout << endl << "After: " << endl;
    printFromReference(bigImage);

    return 0;
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
Before: 
Rows: 2160
Cols: 7680
Step: 7680
Size: 16588800

After: 
Rows: 2160
Cols: 7680
Step: 7680
Size: 16588800
```

So, I'm inclined to agree with SSteve...something else you're doing isn't working correctly... If your step size seems incorrect in the `SplitCVMatrix` function, then you need to make sure your `ConvertToCVType` function telling the constructor the appropriate number of channels to create. This is just a guess though; some code would be helpful :)